# random() always produce the same number?

Tags: java, user-interface

Here is my code.

```
private int getRandomNumber(int start, int end) {
    Random r = new Random();
    int num = r.nextInt(end-start+1)+start; 
    return num;
}
```

I am implementing a GUI with a button that would generate a random password length each time I click the button. So I set passlength:

```
passLength = getRandomNumber(min,max);
```

and when I print out passLength, it give me the same number(the min number,in fact) each time I click it. How do I make it so that I can generate a different number every click?

Comment: What are the values of `start` and `end`?

Comment: Check that `end-start+1` is not equals to 1. I.e `end` must be `> start`.

Comment: start is minimal value, end is maximum value.

Comment: @user3358049 We undestood that, but what are the values of those variables (`min` and `max`) when you call your function?

Comment: min = Integer.parseInt(lengthField1.getText());
max = Integer.parseInt(lengthField1.getText());               These are the codes for the GUI, min and max is what the users types in as inputs.

Comment: @user3358049 And what are these values? What do you input in your fields to test?

Answer (score 1):

Don't create a new random-number generator (`new Random()`) every time. Create one, assign it to a persistent variable (member or static), and call it repeatedly.

Comment: Your second paragraph doesn't add anything, because the no-arg constructor for Random already uses System.nanoTime to provide different seeds.

Comment: Couldn't remember offhand whether that was the default or not, and was feeling paranoid. Thanks for the sanity-check.

Comment: Could you explain more of how to fix this code? Like an example would be perfect. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your problem is elsewhere. I tested the following code and got what would be expected: psuedorandoms in [start, end]. Instantiating the `Random` class once or every time makes no difference.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class TestRandom {

    public TestRandom () {
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            System.out.print(getRandomNumber(0,200) + " ");
        }
    }

    private int getRandomNumber(int start, int end) {
        Random r = new Random();
        int num = r.nextInt(end-start+1)+start;
        return num;
    }
}
```

Sample results were:

190 177 137 184 146 177 54 110 148 172 127 130 110 152 161 197 181 156 33 191 0 62 130 31 35 82 3 123 88 122

101 160 145 174 179 81 73 78 84 10 59 14 189 145 41 198 133 72 129 96 79 104 184 178 55 56 142 14 70 14

109 18 136 20 13 47 67 0 96 179 29 127 11 128 147 143 92 160 144 194 192 194 89 25 67 181 102 154 33 152

etc.

Comment: What do you suppose my problem come from? Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you're handling the button click event properly, making sure the field that's displaying the random number you're generating is being refreshed? It could be lots of things, but I believe the getRandomNumber method is sound.

Comment: Right now, the random number always turn out to be the minimum value entered.

Comment: Can you try separating my example from your existing code and running it by itself? Or posting more of your own code?